# How to save derived type (TPT) in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have problems with saving derived type (TPT) with Entity Framework to database.

Let's say I have base entity Animal and derived type Dog.

I want to save Dog entity.

I thought that I could do it like `contex.AddToDogs()`, but contex contain only base entity - Animal. So I can only save Animal object - `contex.AddToAnimals()`.

I have also tried with `contex.AddObject("Animals", dogInstance)`, but I get the following error:

`The member with identity 'NavigationProperty' does not exist in the metadata collection.`

But I have add EntityReference to the "NavigationProperty".

So how to save derived type in EF?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `contex.AddObject("Animals", dogInstance)`.

Originally I got error on this, but error just says NOT the navigation property name is wrong, but the Entity Set Name is wrong. And it really was. So I fix it and now saving is working properly (Dog is saved to the animal and the Dog table).

Comment: contex.AddObject("Animals", dogInstance) gives me "The specified value is not an instance of a valid constant type\r\nParameter name: value".

Answer (score 0):

If there is no dog entity you will not have a AddToDogs() method no matter what references you add, EF doesn't know how to automatically map derived types to entities. You can either create a function that maps one object to another or use a tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

If I'm taking your question too literally and you are taking a code-first approach then for an explanation of inheritance and association in EF look at [this](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-1.aspx)